# Python: get time difference between 2 time columns of dataframe and filter them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My `time.csv` is like:

```
end_date               start_date
2017-01-01 17:00:00    2017-01-01 16:30:00
2017-01-03 17:05:00    2016-01-03 21:05:00
```

I want to add another column `duration` that contains the difference in `hours`. Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df_time = pd.read_csv('time.csv')

df_time["duration"] = (datetime.strptime(df_time["end_date"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - \
                       datetime.strptime(df_time["start_date"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))/ \
                       timedelta(hours = 1)

print(df_time["duration"].head())
```

But I got the following error

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

How do I convert Series to `str` so that the parse function works?
Secondly, how do I truncate the top 1% longest of duration?

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime(df_time['end_date'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Quang Hoang said, you can convert the time series column from `string` into `Timestamp` format and then it will be easy to find the duration between them.

```js
import pandas as pd

time_data = pd.read_csv("time.csv")
time_data.loc[: , 'end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(time_data.loc[: , 'end_date'])
time_data.loc[: , 'start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(time_data.loc[: , 'start_date'])

time_data['duration'] = time_data['end_date'] - time_data['start_date']
```

Here is the screenshot of the output:

[image]

Hope it helps :)